# Next.js - Page not getting GetServerSideProps into Page component props (with custom _app.js)

Tags: javascript, next.js

I've been trying to add `GetServerSideProps` to my Next.js app, but when trying to do so, the response data is not being injected into the page props.
When looking into the Network Tab, i see the `pageName.json` generating, so the call is being executed and the data being fetched, it just doesn't get into the Page as Props.

Here's my page component.ts

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { url } from "../app/helpers/api/apiEnvs";
import { Button, Spin, Skeleton } from "antd";
import { MailOutlined, LoadingOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import withLayout from "../app/components/Layout";
import './quotes.scss'

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
const res = await fetch(`${url}/estimator/start`,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        });
    const estimator = await res.json();
    return {
        props: { estimator }
    };
};


const Quotes = (props: any) => {

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const antIcon = <LoadingOutlined style={{ fontSize: 24 }} spin />;

    return (
        <div className="quotesContainer">
            <h1>Cotizador</h1>
            <div className="quoteBox quoteStepper">
            <MailOutlined/>
            </div>
            <div className="quoteBox quoteContent">
            {loading
                ? <Spin indicator={antIcon} />
            : <div>
                    <Skeleton.Input style={{ width: '300px' }} active={true} size="large" />
                    <p>{props.estimation ? props.estimation: 'No estimation'}</p>

                    <Skeleton.Button style={{ width: '90px' }} active={true} size="default" />
                    <Button type="primary">
                        Next
                    </Button>
              </div>
            }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default withLayout(Quotes);
```

Custom _app.js Component

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

screenshot of the data being displayed in the [network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYPw4.png)

could it be related to having ts pages and .js _app?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, the issue was with the wrapper,

> Note: Use Layout components (which in my case is in the hole app) inside _app.js

Comment: what does this mean?

Comment: I don't understand :-(

Comment: You'll have more information about it here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/15993

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the loaded props wont passed through your withLayout-wrapper.
Can u post the content of your withLayout-wrapper?

I had the same problem with the withRedux-wrapper from next-redux-wrapper.
Inside the wrapper should be a static async getInitialProps function which do the same like the default getInitialProps from next itself:

```
async function appGetInitialProps({ Component, ctx}:AppContext): Promise<AppInitialProps> {
    const pageProps = await loadGetInitialProps(Component, ctx)
    return { pageProps }
}
```

The loadGetInitialProps function comes with next and can be be imported from next/dist/next-server/lib/utils

Comment: here's the withLayout component
`import React from 'react';`
`import Header from "./header";`


`const withLayout = (Page: any) => {
    return () => (
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <Page />
        </div>
    );
};`

`export default withLayout;`

Comment: so, i've found out you are correct, is. the wrapper, but i cant figure out how to make your function work, so maybe i'll have to refactor the wrapper. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try change _app.js  like this

```
  static async getInitialProps(appContext) {

    const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);

    if (!Object.keys(appProps.pageProps).length) {
      delete appProps.pageProps;
    }

    return appProps;
  }
```

If the return of _app getInitialProps is empty object. NextJs will use the props returned from getServerSideProps if available

Answer (score 0):

There might be custom `_app.js` in which you must be calling `getInitialProps`.
there some modification is required

```
static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
     const pageProps = Component.getInitialProps ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx) : {};

    if (Object.keys(pageProps).length > 0) {
      // return pageProps only when its present
      return { pageProps }; 
    
    }
    return {};
  }
```

yes, you have to return `pageProps` only when it is present.